# Why this question gets so many upvotes and no closevotes at all?

Tags: discussion, questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720165/does-not-get-validated-using-pdo is an exemplary off topic. Even tagging makes it not a real one, as [android] and [pdo] has absolutely nothing to do with each other. To get a valid question one have to stick to only one of these tags.

Why community is so eager to reward the offtopic question?

Why people are so eager to start forum-like discussions in the comments?

And why nobody cares to close it?

Comment: I guess "tim lost his keys" equally applies to upvotes....

Comment: clearly this is just meta effect baiting. the obvious reason is *"it's a php question"*

Comment: Why so many upvotes? In part because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3078121/kostasmatrix?tab=reputation

Answer (score 4):

It has a *chance*, at least, to be edited with more details into it.  I don't want to make the presumption that the OP is merely trying to use this as a forum; I still want to give them the benefit of the doubt.

The major failing of the post, aside from it being in PHP<sup><sup><sup>Cheap shot!</sup></sup></sup> is that it's lacking critical error information from the server-side code.
  Once that's added in, and a bit of polish is added to the grammar of the question, it'll be *fine*.

I don't think that this is a bad question, it's just a typical question; someone has a problem and didn't do the due diligence to research it a bit further.  Don't hate on 'em for that, since you'll be tiring yourself out before too long; cast your close vote and give them time to come back to the question.